# Error starting react project

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, webpack

I'm following [this tutorial](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/how-to-build-react-apps-on-top-of-the-wordpress-rest-api-bcc632808025) on building a React app on top of WordPress, and I'm having trouble starting it.

I modified `package.json` file a bit and webpack.config.js` and I am getting the following error in my terminal

```
➜  wp-api git:(development) ✗ npm start

> wp-api@1.0.0 start /Users/myuser/Projects/wp-api
> webpack-dev-server --open

Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.resolve has an unknown property 'modulesDirectories'. These properties are valid:
   object { alias?, aliasFields?, cachePredicate?, descriptionFiles?, enforceExtension?, enforceModuleExtension?, extensions?, fileSystem?, mainFields?, mainFiles?, moduleExtensions?, modules?, plugins?, resolver?, symlinks?, unsafeCache?, useSyncFileSystemCalls? }
 - configuration.resolve.extensions[0] should not be empty.

npm ERR! Darwin 16.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.10.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v7.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! wp-api@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --open`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the wp-api@1.0.0 start script 'webpack-dev-server --open'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the wp-api package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack-dev-server --open
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs wp-api
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls wp-api
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/myuser/.npm/_logs/2017-05-15T07_40_36_249Z-debug.log
```

The log file is

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.10.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@4.2.0
3 info using node@v7.10.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle wp-api@1.0.0~prestart: wp-api@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle wp-api@1.0.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
7 info lifecycle wp-api@1.0.0~start: wp-api@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle wp-api@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle wp-api@1.0.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/Users/myuser/Projects/wp-api/node_modules/.bin:/Users/myuser/.rbenv/shims:/Users/myuser/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
10 verbose lifecycle wp-api@1.0.0~start: CWD: /Users/myuser/Projects/wp-api
11 silly lifecycle wp-api@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'webpack-dev-server --open' ]
12 silly lifecycle wp-api@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle wp-api@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: wp-api@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --open`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:279:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:194:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:899:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid wp-api@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd /Users/myuser/Projects/wp-api
17 error Darwin 16.5.0
18 error argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.10.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
19 error node v7.10.0
20 error npm  v4.2.0
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error errno 1
23 error wp-api@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --open`
23 error Exit status 1
24 error Failed at the wp-api@1.0.0 start script 'webpack-dev-server --open'.
24 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
24 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the wp-api package,
24 error not with npm itself.
24 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
24 error     webpack-dev-server --open
24 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
24 error     npm bugs wp-api
24 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
24 error     npm owner ls wp-api
24 error There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

The `package.json` and `webpack.config.js` are:

```
{
  "name": "wp-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "React based WordPress app",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "alt": "^0.18.6",
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.8",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-router": "^3.0.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.4.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^3.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.1",
    "webpack": "^2.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "env",
      "react"
    ]
  },
  "author": "dingo-d",
  "license": "GPL"
}
```

and

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path    = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const outputCss = 'styles/[name].css';

var config = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map', // This will show line numbers where errors are accured in the terminal
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true, // This will make the server understand "/some-link" routs instead of "/#/some-link"
  },
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:8080/', // Specify the local server port
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server', // Enable hot reloading
    './src/index' // This is where Webpack will be looking for the entry index.js file
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'), // This is used to specify folder for producion bundle. Will not be used here, but it's a good practice to have it
    filename: 'bundle.js' // Filename for production bundle
    // publicPath: '/'
  },
  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'], // Folders where Webpack is going to look for files to bundle together
    extensions: ['', '.js'] // Extensions that Webpack is going to expect
  },
  module: {
    // Loaders allow you to preprocess files as you require() or “load” them. Loaders are kind of like “tasks” in other build tools, and provide a powerful way to handle frontend build steps.
    loaders: [
      {
      test: /\.jsx?$/, // Here we're going to use JS for react components but including JSX in case this extension is prefered
      exclude: /node_modules/, // Speaks for itself
      loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015'] // Modules that help with hot reloading and ES6 transcription
      }
    ],
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(js)$/, use: 'babel-loader' },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'css-loader'
            },
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader'
            }
          ]
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(), // Hot reloading
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(), // Webpack will let you know if there are any errors
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'index.html'
    }),
  ]
}

module.exports = config;
```

I haven't done much projects with webpack, so my knowledge in this aspect is very limited.

What am I doing wrong? I tried deleting the `node_modules` folder and running `npm install` again, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Solution to the 1st problem:

```
npm uninstall webpack --save-dev
npm install webpack@2.1.0-beta.22 --save-dev
```

Solution to the

`configuration.resolve.extensions[0] should not be empty.` :

Remove `''` from the array

```
resolve: {
modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'], // Folders where Webpack is going to look for files to bundle together
extensions: ['.js'] // Extensions that Webpack is going to expect
},
```

Or replace it with `'*'`

```
resolve: {
modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'], // Folders where Webpack is going to look for files to bundle together
extensions: ['*','.js'] // Extensions that Webpack is going to expect
},
```

Comment: Strange - does it complain about `configuration.resolve.extensions[0] should not be empty.` ?

Comment: I don't see a complain about that, but `configuration.resolve has an unknown property 'modulesDirectories'`

Comment: Does `webpack-dev-server` has to be globally installed?

Comment: in your case - not. Since you run `npm run start`

Comment: I renamed `modulesDirectories` to `modules` and it worked. I am getting some other errors, but I will figure those out.

Comment: well. It seems that your tutorial works with webpack version 1.

Comment: npm uninstall webpack  webpack-dev-server  --save-dev

Comment: and then `npm install --save dev webpack@1.2.19 webpack-dev-server@1.14.0`

Comment: and you will be able to go with moduleDirectories

Comment: I'll leave `modules` and keep the never version. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: good decision. For any forthcoming errors - check the packages compatibility first